# Is there a way to generate some set of rows exactly once on demand in Postgres?

Tags: postgresql, locks, mutual-exclusion

The basic problem is that we are managing a significant amount of generated rows, and it is mission critical that this data is generated exactly once and only if necessary. Suppose you have a data relation:

```
CREATE TABLE sometable (
    id SERIAL,
    refID INTEGER,
    ...
);
```

Now, in some PL/PGSQL function we have:

```
...
-- Advisory locks didn't help here? :(
IF FALSE = SELECT EXISTS( SELECT 1 FROM sometable WHERE refID = dataID) THEN
    -- Generate fixed number of new rows in sometable that reference dataID.
END IF;
...
```

In short, the rows that should *not* be generated more than once some times are. As noted, advisory locks of the form `PERFORM pg_advisory_lock(dataID)` sadly did not help prevent this. Is there any hope?

EDIT: Forgot to mention that I ran into the duplicate data issue when testing with pgbench.

EDIT 2: Incorrect code fix, clarify issue.

Comment: you will get a better response if you post the question on http://dba.stackexchange.com

Comment: What exactly is your problem? Can you explain what triggers the function call, why you need a lock and what it is that the lock did not help with?

Comment: Also: `PERFORM * FROM sometable WHERE refID = dataID; IF found THEN ... END IF;`

Comment: Thanks for note Patrick, I've updated it to more clearly state the issue. Basically the rows that should (and must) only be generated once is being generated multiple times.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Perhaps the simplest solution is just to have a separate `processed_ids` table with a unique constraint on the id in question. Your function can try to insert to that table and if there is an exception then that ID is already processed.

Comment: Yup, that worked for me. I also had to add a while loop in the exception catching code that appropriately waits for the correct number of rows to be generated by the function call that _does_ manage to insert into `processed_ids` table, which might not work for others with a similar issue if its not clear how many rows should be calculated. But if you do, then you are golden!